# Plot only specific subplots of a grid of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a grid of subplots to my liking.
I initiated the plotting by defining `fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,6,figsize=(24,8))`

So far so good. I filled those subplots with their respective content. Now I want to plot a single or two particular subplot in isolation. I tried:

```
ax[idx][idx].plot()
```

This does not work and returns an empty list

I have tried:

```
fig_single,ax_single = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax_single[0]=ax[idx][0]
ax_single[1]=ax[idx][1]
```

This returns:

```
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support item assignment
```

How do I proceed without plotting those subplots again by calling the respective plot functions?

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=6,sharex=False,sharey=False,figsize=(24,8)) 
#set either sharex=True or sharey=True if you wish axis limits to be shared 
#=> very handy for interactive exploration of timeseries data, ...

r=0 #first row
c=0 #first column
ax[r,c].plot() #plot your data, instead of ax[r][c].plot()
ax[r,c].set_title() #name title for a subplot
ax[r,c].set_ylabel('Ylabel ') #ylabel for a subplot
ax[r,c].set_xlabel('X axis label') #xlabel for a subplot
```

A more complete/flexible method is to assign r,c:

```
for i in range(nrows*ncols):
    r,c = np.divmod(i,ncols)
    ax[r,c].plot() #....
```

You can afterwards still make modifications, e.g. set_ylim, set_title, ...

So if you want to name the label of the 11th subplot:

```
ax[2,4].set_ylabel('11th subplot ylabel')
```

You will often want to make use of `fig.tight_layout()` at the end, so that the figure uses the available area correctly.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,180,180)

nrows = 2
ncols = 6

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows,ncols=ncols,sharex=False,sharey=False,figsize=(24,8))
for i in range(nrows*ncols):
    r,c = np.divmod(i,ncols)
    y = np.sin(x*180/np.pi*(i+1))
    ax[r,c].plot(x,y)
    ax[r,c].set_title('%s'%i)

fig.suptitle('Overall figure title')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: Example 2x6 subplots]